# C programming language,how to convert input string in code and run it

Tags: c

Is there a way to transform what the user inputs in code?
 like 
if

```
char k[50]; 
printf("insert the code to insert");
scanf("%s", &k);
```

function => 
  converts string and execute the string if the code is correct

for example
  if the user insert `"int a = 0;"` 
as input , the program  run the input string?

Comment: Write it to file, feed to compiler, and execute the result..

Comment: This can't be practically done in C, as it is compiled language with no introspection or reflection fearures.

Comment: What you want is a scripting interpreter.  There are plenty of 3rd party interpreters available

Comment: How can this be considered to broad? It's a good question.

Comment: Do you want to be able to evaluate truly arbitrary C programs, or relatively simple expressions?  Evaluating expressions is a much more straightforward problem -- even more so if you restrict yourself to constants, with no variables.  (But in any case the answer is still "no", there's no way to do this defined within the context of the Standard C language.  You'd have to use a third-party function or library to do the evaluation.  Such do exist -- I''ve written a few.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is essentially something like the `eval` function that some languages has.

Nope, there is not a way to do that. At least not in a practical way. The reason is quite simple. In C, you need to compile the complete program before you run it. If there is even a single syntax error in you 10k+ lines of code, you will not get an executable binary from the compiler.

Python on the other hand can execute line by line. That's why you can execute Python code that has syntax errors. The program will not crash until you encounter the error.

Besides, you should always think twice before using something like this irregardless of the language. The risks for vulnerabilities are extremely high.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to some other languages, the C language doesn't have an eval function to do what you want. The only option is to write the source file into a file and then execute the compiler available on the host machine.